# How to return a nested list of frequency from a Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From a list of cards - return a nested list of the cards with the same numbers and then the rest in a separate list.

```
EXAMPLE: ['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']
```

returning `[['7C', '7D'], ['6C','6D'], ['8S']]`

I have attempted using a while loop, but cant figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your attempt

Comment: [edit] the question and include your code using `while` loop please.

Comment: Look into using `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: "...rest in a separate list..." what if your list also has "9K"... does this go into the same list as "8S" or does it go into a separate list?

Comment: `[list(j) for i,j in groupby(sorted(['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']),lambda x: x[0])]`

Answer (score 1):

Here. Try this.

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']
a.sort()
final_list = []
for i, j in groupby(a, key=lambda x:x[0]):
    final_list.append(list(j))
print(final_list)
```

Comment: `[list(j) for i,j in (groupby(sorted(['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']),lambda x: x[0]))]`

Comment: Sure. we can do it this way. I just thought it would be much more understandable if I do one step at a time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to sort the list, then group the list using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), both by using the integer part of the string, and then grouping items with common integer elements together

```
from itertools import groupby
li = ['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']

#Sort the list based on the integer part of the string
li = sorted(li, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))

#Group the list based on the integer part of the string
res = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(li, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[['6C', '6D'], ['7C', '7D'], ['8S']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an optimal solution but...

```
a = ['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']
item = []
ls = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i][0] in ls:
    continue
  else:
    ls.append(a[i][0])
    temp = []
    temp.append(a[i])
    for j in range((i+1), len(a)):
      if a[i][0] == a[j][0]:
        temp.append(a[j])
      else:
        continue
    item.append(temp)
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without using itertools groupby.

```
l = ['6C', '7C', '7D', '8S', '6D']

result, temp = [], []

l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])

counter = l[0][0]


for i in l:
    if i[0] == counter:
        temp.append(i)

    else:
        result.append(temp)
        temp = [i]
        counter = i[0]

if temp:
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```